# Sequentially continuous implies continuous

Tags: general-topology

In topological spaces, which condition is necessary for a sequentially continous function $f: (X,\tau_x) \rightarrow (Y,\tau_y)$ to be continous?

I have tried to prove this making the space X be $T_1$ and then making it Hausdorff but I don't get the answer. For example making $\tau_x$ the topology of the complements of countable sets is $T_1$ and $f(x) = x$ is sequentially continuous but not continuous taking $X=Y= \mathbb{R}$ and $\tau_y$ being the usual topology in $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: Read about "sequential spaces".

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countability and follow the links given one that page.

Answer (score 19):

A function $f$ between topological spaces is *sequentially continuous* if the image of every convergent sequence is a sequence which converges to the image of the limit.

Continuity always implies sequential continuity: Suppose $x_n\rightarrow x$. Then if $U$ is any open neighborhood of $f(x)$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is a neighborhood of $x$ which (by continuity of $f$) is open. Because $x_n\rightarrow x$, every neighborhood of $x$ contains a tail of the sequence. In particular, $f^{-1}(U)$ contains a tail of the sequence. Hence $f(f^{-1}(U))\subseteq U$ contains the image of the tail, which is a tail of the image. Since $U$ was arbitrary, we have that every neighborhood $U \ni f(x)$ contains a tail of the image of the sequence. This means that $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$.

A space is called *first countable* if for each point $x$, there is a *countable* collection of open sets around $x$ such that any set around $x$ contains some member of the collection.

In a first-countable space, the entire topology (open and closed sets) can be characterized in terms of sequences. Moreover, **for functions whose domain is a first-countable space, sequential continuity implies continuity**: suppose $f$ is sequentially continuous. Pick any point $x$; we will show that $f$ is continuous at $x$. Suppose $x_n\rightarrow x$. Then $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$ by sequential continuity. Hence every neighborhood $U\ni f(x)$ contains a tail of the image of the sequence. Hence $f^{-1}(U)$ contains a tail of the sequence itself. We can't assume that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open (because we haven't proved that $f$ is continuous), but by first countability, we know that $f^{-1}(U)$ contains an open set $V \ni x$.  We know that $V\subseteq f^{-1}(U)$, so $f(V)\subseteq U$, so $f$ is continuous at $x$.

More generally, we use the term **sequential spaces** to refer to the collection of topological spaces for which sequential continuity implies continuity. All first countable spaces are sequential spaces, as we have shown. And there are others: consider $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$; the real line with its usual topology, but where the integers have been unified to a single point. You can show that this space is not first countable, but it is sequential nonetheless.

$\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ isn't first countable: you can visualize the space as a countable number of circular loops splayed out in 3D space; the circles all meet at a single origin point 0. Each loop corresponds to an interval between integers $[n,n+1]$.  The space fails to be first countable because we can't find the required countable basis for the origin point 0. For contradiction, suppose we have a collection $C$ of open sets that we want to prove is a countable basis for 0. Consider the loops of this space: how many members of $C$ does each loop contain? If $C$ is countable, there must be at least one loop $[n,n+1]$ that contains finitely many members of $C$. But then we can find a set $[n+\frac{1}{2} - \epsilon, n+\frac{1}{2} + \epsilon]$ which is smaller than the smallest such member of $C$. This set is a neighborhood of 0 but contains no member of $C$, so $C$ is not a basis for the point 0.

I don't know if there is any other surprising defining characteristic of sequential spaces besides its straightforward definition.

Comment: sequentially closed sets are closed, is the definition. The continuity part then follows. See my answer.

Comment: In the proof that seq. continuity over a 1-countable space implies continuity it seems to me that you cannot use 1-countability directly to conclude that $f^{-1}(U)$ contains an open set. 1-countability only tells you that you have a countable neighborhood basis for $x$, so you first need to prove that $f^{-1}(U)$ is a neighborhood of $x$...which, by def., means that it contains an open set! I'd suggest to go by contradiction: assume it is not and use 1-countability to define a sequence converging to $x$ but not contained in $f^{-1}(U)$, which contradicts the seq. continuity of $f$.

Comment: I am having a few doubts regarding $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: It is not true in general that $f(f^{-1}(U)) = U$.

Answer (score 10):

We have to consider sequential domain spaces $X$.

A space $X$ is sequential when for all  sequentially closed subsets $A$ of $X$, $A$ is closed in $X$.

$A \subseteq X$ is said to be sequentially closed, iff for all sequences $(a_n)$ in $A$ (i.e. all $a_n \in A$) such that $a_n \to x$ (in $X$), we have $x \in A$ as well. Note that always all closed sets are sequentially closed. But e.g. in the co-countable topology all convergent sequences are eventually constant, which implies *all* subsets of $X$ are sequentially closed (but not all subsets are closed).

It is well-known that all first countable spaces are sequential (this includes all metric spaces).

> Theorem: if $f:X \to Y$ is sequentially continuous, and $X$ is sequential then $f$ is continuous.

Proof: let $C$ be closed in $Y$, we'll show that $A = f^{-1}[C]$ is closed in $X$. For this we only need to show it is sequentially closed. So let $a_n \in A$ be a sequence such that $a_n \to x$. Then $f(a_n ) \to f(x)$ by sequential continuity. But $f(a_n) \in C$ by definition of $A$, so as $C$ is closed, $f(x) \in C$, which says $x \in f^{-1}[C] = A$, as required. So $f^{-1}[C]$ is closed in $X$ for all closed $C$ in $Y$, hence $f$ is continuous.

Suppose that $X$ obeys the conclusion of the theorem (all sequentially continuous maps on $X$ are continuous). If $X$ were not sequential we'd have a subset $A$ of $X$ that is sequentially closed but not closed. Consider $\tau'$: the topology generated by $\tau_X$ and $X\setminus A$. I think we can show that the identity $(X, \tau_X)$ to $(X,\tau')$ is sequentially continuous, and it is certainly not continuous.

So in a way, being a sequential space is the natural notion here to consider.

Answer (score 4):

Proposition: if $(X, \mathscr T)$ and $(Y, \mathscr S)$ are topological spaces, **$X$ is first countable**, and $f: X → Y$  is sequentially continuous, then $f$ is continuous.

Proof: by contra-positive
Recall,
**A:** A (countable) local base for a topological space $(X, \mathscr T)$ at a point $x$ is a (countable) collection of open sets $\{X_i \in \mathscr T\}$ containing $x$,  such that any open set $O$ that contains $x$ contains one of the sets $X_i$.
**B:** if there is a countable local base at $x$, then there is also a nested (descending sequence of sets) countable local base.
**C:** A topological space is first countable if for every point $x \in X$ there is a (possibly different) (nested) countable local base.
**D:** if $(X, \mathscr T)$ and $(Y, \mathscr S)$  are topological spaces, a function $f: X → Y$ is discontinuous at a point $x \in X$ if for some open set $V$ with $f(x) \in V$ then for every open set $U \in X$ with $x \in U$, $U \not\subset f^{-1}(V)$: equivalently $f (U) ⊄ V$.
**E:** An (infinite) sequence of points $(x_n) \in X$ converges to a limit $x \in X$ if for every open set $O$ containing $x$ there is $N$ such that for all $n > N$ then $x_n \in O$.

Suppose that $f: X → Y$ is not continuous $\implies$ it is not continuous at some point $x$.
Then by (D) there is some open set $V ⊂ Y$ with $f(x) \in V$ and for every open set $U \subset X$ with $x \in U, f (U) \not \subset V$.
Since $X$ is first countable, there is a nested countable local base $(X_i)$ at $x$, each $X_i$ is open, and by the previous sentence  $f (X_i) \not \subset V$.
So for each of the nested $X_i, f (X_i) \not \subset V \implies$ there is some $x_i \in X_i$ with $f(x_i) \not \in V$.
Pick one from each $X_i$ and consider the sequence $(x_i)$.

By (E), the sequence $(x_i)$ converges to x since....
For any open set $O \in X$ which contains $x$ there is some $X_i$ with $x \in X_i \subset O$ (definition of a local base)
And for $j \ge i$ then because the local base is nested, all $x_j \in X_j \subset O$.
So, for any open set $O \in X$ which contains $x$ there is $i$ such that for $j \ge i$ then $x_j \in O$, which is the condition that $(x_i)$ converges to $x$.

But $V$ is open and $f(x) \in V$ and for all $i$,  $f(x_i) \not \in V$, i.e. $(f(x_i))$ doesn't converge to $f(x)$.

So if $f$ is not continuous then it is not sequentially continuous and the result follows.

Answer (score 3):

In 1st countable spaces sequential continuity implies continuity.
In general, net continuity implies continuity.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which gives a very resounding *no* answer.

In the space $X=\beta\mathbf N\setminus \bf N$ is compact Hausdorff and all convergent sequences are eventually constant. It easily follows that every function $X\to Y$ is sequentially continuous, even though $X$ is not discrete, so there are lots of discontinuous functions from $X$.

To obtain a characterisation of continuity in terms similar to sequential continuity, you have to use [nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)). It is a fairly standard exercise to show that a function $f\colon X\to Y$ is continuous if and only if for each net $(x_i)_i$ in $X$ convergent to some $x$, the net $(f(x_i))_i$ is convergent to $f(x)$.

In fact, if $Y$ is $T_1$, then it is enough to assume that $f$ maps convergent nets to convergent nets (preservation of limits follows automatically), see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3756101/30222).